# bootstrap dropdown multiselect with tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with multiselect and tags. currently I am using this [plugin](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) which has options, but I am in need of tags with it. As you can see in below attached image:

[image]

In the above image, the first drop down is the default from the plugin. I need it to convert it in to the 2nd drop down. the only problem is, it doesn't support tag. If anyone would be able to help with this plaugin or any other option, I will be thankful.

Comment: Please share your html/code/css with us.

Comment: Consider using https://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/#section-Examples